# JAR File Open and Closes Instantly

Tags: java, jar

I made a random number generator which works fine in the console in Eclipse, but when I export it as JAR and double click on it, it opens up and then closes right away. How can I fix this? There is no errors at all when exporting so I am kind of confused.

Here is the code

```java
package stajeovo;

import java.util.Random;

public class probatu {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        System.out.println("Ok Dragisa!, Evo ti su Random brojovi! " + "\r\n");

        Random drag = new Random();
        Random drag1 = new Random();
        Random drag2 = new Random();
        Random drag3 = new Random();
        Random drag4 = new Random();
        Random drag5 = new Random();
        Random drag6 = new Random();

        int max = 50;
        int min = 1;

        
        int broj2 = ((49 + 1) -1) + 1;
        int broj3 = 50;
        int broj4 = 50;
        int broj5 = 50;
        int broj7 = 50;
        
        int int_random = drag.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min;
        int int_random1 = drag1.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min;
        int int_random2 = drag2.nextInt(broj2);
        int int_random3 = drag3.nextInt(broj3);
        int int_random4 = drag4.nextInt(broj4);
        int int_random5 = drag5.nextInt(broj5);
        int int_random6 = drag6.nextInt(broj7);

        System.out.println("Evo ti prvi broj : " + " : " + int_random );
        System.out.println("Evo ti drugi broj : " + " : " + int_random1);
        System.out.println("Evo ti treci broj : " + int_random2);
        System.out.println("Evo ti cetvrti broj : " + int_random3);
        System.out.println("Evo ti peti broj : " + int_random4);
        System.out.println("Evo ti sesti broj : " + int_random5);
        System.out.println("Evo ti sedmi broj : " + int_random6 + "\r\n");

        System.out.println("Hajde sada vise pobjedi!!! :) ");



    }

}
```

Comment: My guess is it opens, prints that stuff, and then closes right after because you didn't tell it to, for example, wait a second before closing. Open your terminal (PowerShell on Windows), navigate to wherever the jar is (use `cd`), and then do `java -jar yourfile.jar` and then the output will be there. Or tell it to wait a few seconds at the end of your code.

Comment: No need of powershell though. Simple command prompt ```cmd``` would do

Comment: Can I put Thread.sleep at the end then? Would that work. Sorry Im a newbie just trying to make this for my dad for his lotto numbers

Comment: The default program to 'open' jars on WIndows is normally javaw.exe, which doesn't let the terminal window remain open. I would personally change that to java.exe, then you should see the output

Comment: I just tried using java.exe and it opens flashes then closes when i tried javaw.exe it does nothing. :( not sure what to do or if the Thread.sleep code might work for it? Thanks to all again.

Comment: You can sleep, or use `new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()` or `System.console().readLine()` to wait for an enter (note: this last one generally doesn't work when running from Eclipse).

Comment: hey thank you for the reply. i just tried

try
     {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
     catch(InterruptedException ex)
     {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }

but it didn't do anything different :( and i tried using the java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit: as well but it didn't do anything. I just want it to remain open when i double click on the jar file so my dad can write down the numbers lol